# Divisibility and remainders

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I know that if $d|a$ exists then for there is some $q$ such that $dq+r=a$ where $q$ is our quotient and $r$ is our remainder. Now I know that IF $d$ divides $a$ exactly then we have a remainder of $0$, and so $r\ge 0$.

My textbook however, expands to say $r$ must ALSO be $<d$, so $0\le r<d$. Where does the restriction $r<d$ come from?

Comment: Go through the division algorithm with actual numbers. It will become clear.

Comment: If $r = d,$ then $a = dq+d = d(q+1),$ which implies that $d$ divides $a.$

Comment: If the remainder were any higher, it would be part of the quotient!

Comment: @ChrisLeary That is a fantastic answer, now that helps me convince myself $r<d$. Is there an indirect way of showing $r<d$ using some algebra? For example if one didn't know to test the case $r=d$?

Comment: @Lex_i - If $a$ is not divisible by $d$ it will lie between two consecutive multiples of $d,$ say $qd < a < (q+1)d.$ Subtract $qd$ across the inequalities to see that $0<a-qd < d.$ But $r = a-qd,$ the difference between $a$ and the largest multiple of $q$ that is less than or equal to $a.$ Of course, if $a$ is a multiple of $d$ then $r=0.$

Answer (score 1):

In our usual division algorithm, we choose largest $q$ at each step. We ensure that $a - dq < d$ at every step. This is why $ r =a - dq < d$.